# xslt template match on child element value with specific attribute?

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

Lets say a have this basic xml document:

```
<result name="response" numFound="73" start="0">
    <doc>
        <str name="contentType">Content1</str>
        <str name="content">Some content here</str>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <str name="contentType">Content2</str>
        <str name="content">Some other content</str>
    </doc>
</result>
```

I plan to use a different template for each content type. What are the template match arguments? I haven't been able to figure out how to match for the other children of doc when only the contentType field is a specific value.

Comment: Did you forget a `</doc>` tag on the 4th or 5th line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like what you're going for is something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="doc[str[@name = 'contentType'] = 'Content1']
                     /str[name = 'Content']">
   <!-- Process Content1 content str -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="doc[str[@name = 'contentType'] = 'Content2']
                     /str[name = 'Content']">
   <!-- Process Content2 content str -->
</xsl:template>
```

Or perhaps something like this?

```
<xsl:template match="doc[str[@name = 'contentType'] = 'Content1']">
   <!-- Process Content1 doc -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="doc[str[@name = 'contentType'] = 'Content2']">
   <!-- Process Content2 doc -->
</xsl:template>
```

Would either of those be what you're looking for?

Comment: The 2nd is exactly what I'm looking for. It's also one of the iterations that I tried. It appears most of my trouble was related to a catch-all match on a default template (for unknown content) that was matching with a higher precedence.